# How to upload image using local uri generated by image picker(EXPO) to the server?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to send image or file from mobile to backend but image picker cannot give me the image gives URI that is not recognised.

```
_pickImage = async () => {
let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});

console.log(result);

if (!result.cancelled) {
  this.setState({ files: result.uri });

  // upload file && get File Id
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://someurl",
    data: {
      image: this.state.file
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      // TODO: upadte with dynamic token
      Authorization:
        "Bearer {token}"
    }
  }).then(
    function(response) {
      console.log(response.data.message);
      // this.setState({
      //   hospItems: response.data.data
      // });
    }.bind(this)
  );
}
```

};

console.log(result); returns::
Object {
  "name": "1554736582840.jpg",
  "size": 45240,
  "type": "success",
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540abhinavofficial%252Fmobi-medic/DocumentPicker/cd34bbd8-7c0c-414a-a76d-8d06e2abf670jpg",
}

response from the server:
The image field is required.